# What book is Akihito reading in episode 5 of Kyoukai no Kanata?

Tags: beyond-the-boundary

In episode **5** of **Kyoukai no Kanata**, Akihito is reading a book while he skips school:

[image]

What is this book?

Answer (score 4):

Though it's a little bit difficult to read since his fingers are covering the spine, this book looks like [***Two Billion Light-Years of Solitude***](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/4087462684) (or 二十億光年の孤独), by [Shuntarou TANIKAWA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuntaro_Tanikawa).

[image: Cover of "Two Billion Light-Years of Solitude"]

*Two Billion Light-Years of Solitude* is a collection of poetry - in fact, Tanikawa's first publication, published in 1952.